# What is the meaning of "\\\\.\\C:" and "\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0" in CreateFile?

Tags: c++

I have read the code as following:

```
CreateFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", 
      0, 
      FILE_SHARE_READ
      NULL, 
      OPEN_EXISTING,  
      0, 
     NULL);  

CreateFile("\\\\.\\C:",
        GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);
```

I do not understand the meaning of the path:

```
"\\\\.\\C:"
\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0
```

Could you please help?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why not read the documentation?

Comment: Is this code on MS Windows OS or Unix or Linux? `.\` usually meaning current directory.

Comment: @vcp Linux uses `/dev/sdax`... Only Windows uses `\\.\PhysicalDrive0`

Answer (score 5):

`\\`, in a string, is really just a single backslash, so the 'real' path names are `\\.\C:` and `\\.\PhysicalDrive0`.

That particular notation indicates raw device access: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/100027

Comment: A minor addition: the full documentation on file and path naming can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for that one but couldn't find it.

Comment: first link is 404 now

Answer (score 3):

\\.\PhysicalDrive0 translates to \.\PhysicalDrive0 as a String. This location contains the Master Boot Record.

```
HANDLE MasterBootRecord = CreateFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", GENERIC_ALL, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,      //Get a handle on the MBR File
    NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL, NULL);
```

This is how to properly write the code.